# Loading images from the server is very slow

Tags: android

I am trying to load images from the server and want to know how can i convert the images into the thumbnails so that they get uploaded fast and how can i get the larger images from the thumbnails fast . I have tried many things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A good start would be by telling us what you have tried.

Comment: @vikas please update your code here

Comment: @OctavianDamiean He's tried many things!

Answer (score 0):

At the server you need to keep 2 copies of an image. First is the thumbnail and the other one is the image.
First you need to download the thumbnail asynchronously. And if the user wishes to see it then download the original image asynchronously. While downloading original image you can show the scaled thumbnail image as the placeholder image. So when the downloading is completed show the downloaded image.
Make sure to download the images asynchronously otherwise you will block the main thread and UI will get stuck.

This is how google images work.

In **iOS** there is a very nice API [SWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) which handles the downloading and caching of photos from the web seamlessly. I am sure there must be some API for Android as well.

If you need any help I can help with the code as well.

---

For **Android** you can use [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to download and display image - it can use cache and save memory while loading scaled images.